# Show $T:C([0,1],\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ with $T(x) =\int_0^1 x^2(t) dt$ is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I have already shown that the operator $T:C([0,1],\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ with $T(x) =\int_0^1 x^2(t) dt$ is well-defined and non-linear. I would like to show that $T$ is (uniformly) continuous. So far I have tried to write
$$ |T(x) - T(y)| = \left|\int_0^1 x^2(t) dt - \int_0^1 y^2(t) dt \right| = \left| \int_0^1 x^2(t) -y^2(t) dt\right| \leq \int_0^1 |x^2(t) -y^2(t)| dt.$$
Since $x^2(t) -y^2(t) = (x(t) + y(t))(x(t)-y(t))$, we have for all $t\in [0,1]$
$$|x^2(t) -y^2(t)| \leq |x(t) + y(t)||x(t)-y(t)| \leq |x(t) + y(t)| \|x-y\|_\infty \leq (\|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty) \|x-y\|_\infty.$$
We thus have
$$ |T(x) - T(y)| \leq (\|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty) \|x-y\|_\infty$$
and if we let $x\to y$ in $C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ the right-hand side tends to zero, implying
$$|T(x) - T(y)| \to 0.$$
Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your fast answer! Is it possible to show uniformly continuity too?

Comment: It is not uniformly continuous : if you consider only constant function, it reduces to $x\mapsto x^2$, which we know isn't.

Comment: @SolubleFish Thats true, thank you! :)

Comment: Good job. Maybe you should explicitely state: (1) the norm that you are working with  (2) the fact that your proof proves continuity but not uniform continuity (because the prefactor in the inequality depends on $x,y$). Just for clarity ?